# Trustpilot API pre-flight not Allowed

Tags: api, axios, preflight, trustpilot

I use axios library in vue for authentication (POST with headers) on Trustpilot but the browser send a pre-fligth calling and the Trustpilot API respond me with error because OPTION method is not Allowed.

I suppose that the authentication request is a simple request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) but axios make it as a not simple request and the browser call a pre-fligth request. There is a method for fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to send? add to question, have you notice:"In the case of a "Basic" authentication like shown in the figure, the exchange must happen over an HTTPS (TLS) connection to be secure."?

Comment: My code is this:
this.axios.request({
                url: 'https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{
                    'grant_type': 'password',
                    'username': 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com',
                    'password': 'xxxxxx'
                },
                headers:{
                    'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })

Comment: The response is this (for the OPTION method) send:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a browser call to the trustpilot oauth endpoint. Cause the Authorization consists of your apikey and secret. Exposing that to a browser client would be vulnerable.

Your server will be able to call the API.

If you don't have a server, then redirect the user to `https://authenticate.trustpilot.com` with your client_id and redirect url, where the user is able to login in.

You can see more details here: https://developers.trustpilot.com/authentication#implicit

Comment: Ok, i suppose i have to wrap the authentication in a cUrl call and return response from a reserved link on my app. For example I make a light api server for the authentication process. OK thanks

Comment: Yeah, exactly. This way you are keeping the secret safe at your back-end.